# How to model table with items which have multiple subcategories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need some advice. I am pretty new in modeling database so I was wondering what would be the most convenient way to model database which would make my life easier. I have one Car item which can have multiple descriptive subcategories, like TireCategory, GlassCategory, EngineCategory...

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tire_category
  belongs_to :glass_category
  belongs_to :engine_category

  #Car would have three additional columns: tire_category_id, glass_category_id, engine_category_id
end

class TireCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class GlassCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class EngineCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

Is this recommended way to do it or some other relation would be more suitable? Thank you!

Comment: yes, i guess that's fine.

Comment: Potentially, you can put all the categories in one table and use STI to separate them, but that may unnecessarily complicate things for you.

Comment: Thank you Paritosh and H-man!

Answer (score 1):

You can store cars (with uniq data like model name and sku) in one table, properties (like engines, glasses) in another, and one more table for relation between cars and properties.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_properties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :properties, through: :car_properties
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_properties, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cars, through: :car_properties
end

class CarProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :property
end
```

If you have a lot of properties and want to logically separate them then create separate models for each property. Like `Engine`, `Tire`, `Glass`. Each model will contain properties variants. Then create one table for each property to connect it to the car. Like `CarEngine`, `CarGlass`. It will contain `car_id` and `property_id` (`engine_id`, `glass_id`).